# Setting up SNMP in PHP

Tags: php, virtual-machine, snmp

I'm pretty new at PHP, and I'm trying to setup SNMP.  I have a server running on a virtual machine, and through the command line on that machine I am able to use commands such as `snmpwalk`.  However, when I try using the method in my PHP code I am getting `Fatal error: Call to undefined function snmpwalk()`. I've seen that others have had this problem, but haven't found any beginner level tutorials on how to fix it.  Any ideas?

Comment: It depends on what OS are you using and how you installed `php` on that OS. `SNMP` module in php is not installed by default and you must compile php with `--with-snmp[=DIR]` flag if you install php from sources. Or install `snmp` php extension on debian. Or install it from ports on FreeBSD.

Comment: @djxak My Virtual machine is running Red Hat with PHP 5.5.22. I did not personally install PHP on this machine so I don't know how it was installed.

Comment: Unfortunately I never working with Red Hat but I'm sure you need to install `php-snmp` package somehow (in usual way of installing packages on Red Hat). Maybe `yum install php-snmp`. See [this link](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/mageia/4/x86_64/media/core/updates/php-snmp-5.5.22-1.2.mga4.x86_64.html).

Comment: @djxak So it looks like that helped.  I ran `yum install php-snmp --skip-broken` and it seems to have installed.  However, after restarting the server, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Why skip-broken? Are you sure that the package is installed? try "rpm -qa | grep snmp" to see what snmp packages are actually installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed php-snmp with the --skip-broken flag. It is very likely that there was a dependency issue, which you have skipped.

As a rule of thumbs, avoid using skip-broken completely